# CS50 pset4 Blur Filter - 1 value deviation from the expected output

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on the blur filter assignment of CS50. It seems there is something wrong with my code for the blur value caculation.

This is my code:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Create a copy of the original image
    RGBTRIPLE tmp[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            tmp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {

            // predefine all the needed variables
            int Sum_Red = 0;
            int Sum_Green = 0;
            int Sum_Blue = 0;
            int COUNT = 0;

            //check the boundary and iterating the funtion within three blocks
            for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++)
            {
                for (int l = -1; l < 2; l++)
                {
                    int new_i = i + k;
                    int new_j = j + l;

                    // Nine block cases
                    if (new_i >= 0 && new_i < height && new_j >= 0 && new_j < width)
                    {
                        Sum_Red += tmp[new_i][new_j].rgbtRed;
                        Sum_Green += tmp[new_i][new_j].rgbtGreen;
                        Sum_Blue += tmp[new_i][new_j].rgbtBlue;
                        COUNT++;
                    }
                }
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(Sum_Red / COUNT);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(Sum_Green / COUNT);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(Sum_Blue / COUNT);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The output looks like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOZtg.png)

It seems that some values are slightly out of the expectation.

I saw other's code as this for the part where I implemented int k and l to avoid boundary:

```
for (int r = -1; r < 2; r++)
            {
                for (int c = -1; c < 2; c++)
                {
                    if (i + r < 0 || i + r > height - 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (j + c < 0 || j + c > width - 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    sumBlue += image[i + r][j + c].rgbtBlue;
                    sumGreen += image[i + r][j + c].rgbtGreen;
                    sumRed += image[i + r][j + c].rgbtRed;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
```

What's the actual difference in math between this code and my code? I do the calculation and intuitively they are the same, however, the output is not the same. Other person's code has the correct output bu using CS50 to check.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `round(Sum_Red / COUNT);` Function `round` does not have any effect in your code because the parameter is already rounded down. Both operands `Sum_Red` and `COUNT` are integers. That means you are doing integer division *before*  you put the result into `round` function. Try `round((double)Sum_Red / COUNT);`

Comment: The important part of that other people's code is probably in the part you did not show. Check what types the variables have. If `sumBlue` etc. are floating point types, there will be no problem. Or they do the division correctly. The code you show is not better than your code.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I knew where the issue comes from... I should define all the variables float instead of int to avoid unexpected trunk off...

```
    float Sum_Red = 0;
    float Sum_Green = 0;
    float Sum_Blue = 0;
    float COUNT = 0;
```

like this.

Comment: That is one option. I showed another one. But generally you should not use `float` variables unless you have some tight memory restrictions. In all other cases you should use `double`.